# Adding a Subscript to a constrained Array

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions

Given a struct `Parameter` which has a `name` and a `value` property, I would like to add a Subscript to an Array which let me return the *value* of the first found element whose *name* matches the subscript parameter.

Usage example:

```
let params = [Parameter("firstName", "John"), Parameter("lastName", "Doh")]    
let value = params["firstName"] // returns "John"
```

**Edit:**
The compiler error occurs only, if I define the array as follows:

```
let params: [ParameterType] = [Parameter("firstName", "John"), Parameter("lastName", "Doh")]    
let value = params["firstName"] // returns "John"
```

Now, when I implement it, I get a compiler error:

```
error: ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
        let value = params["firstName"] // returns "John"
                    ^~~~~~

note: found this candidate
    public subscript (index: Int) -> Element { get set }

note: found this candidate
    public subscript (name: String) -> String? { get set }

note: found this candidate
    public subscript (bounds: Range<Self.Index>) -> MutableSlice<Self> { get set }

note: found this candidate
    public subscript (position: Self.Index) -> Self.Base.Generator.Element { get }
```

**So, why is this ambiguous?**

That doesn't make sense to me.

Note: all the other candidates are implementations for struct Array defined within the standard library.

For example how is

`subscript (index: Int) -> Element` and

`subscript (name: String) -> String?`

ambiguous?

I suspect, the error messages are just confusing, and the true error is because type parameter `Element` is not fully specified. Anyway, how could this be implemented?

---

This is my attempt to implement it.

I am aware, that - due to the current limitations in the language - the subscript implementation is actually defined for a *set* of Element types conforming to `ParameterType`:

```
public protocol ParameterType {
    init(_ name: String, _ value: String)
    var name: String { get }
    var value: String { get }
}

public extension Array where Element: ParameterType {

    subscript(name: String) -> String? {
        get {
            let a = self.filter { $0.name == name }
            if let e = a.first {
                return e.value
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set(newValue) {
            let i = self.index { $0.name == name }
            if let index = i {
                if let value = newValue {
                    self[index] = Element(name, value)
                } else {
                    self.remove(at:index)
                }
            } else {
                if let value = newValue {
                    let param = Element(name, value)
                    self.append(param)
                } else { /* */ }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here is one concrete type conforming to `ParameterType`:

```
public struct Parameter: ParameterType {
    public init(_ name: String, _ value: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
    public var name: String
    public var value: String
}
```

**Note:**

Constraining the array to a *class* type doesn't solve it: the same errors will be emitted.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code compiles for me, and `params["firstName"]` returns `Optional("John")`.

Comment: @MartinR This is Version 7.3 beta (7D152p)  (beta 4). I'll Check this with beta 5 and the most recent release.

Comment: @MartinR I think I found the issue: I defined my array as this: ` var params: Parameters = [param]` where `Parameters` equals `typealias Parameters = [ParameterType]` . If I omit the explicit type annotation - as in my sample above - it works as expected. Still, now I'm wondering why ... ;)

Comment: This looks like  a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself: With `let params : [ParameterType] = ...` the array elements are of the  *protocol type* ParameterType, and a protocol does not conform to itself. Without the annotation, `params` has the type `[Parameter]` and the elements are of the *concrete type* Parameter.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it seems to be this same issue. Interestingly: the current release will emit a more clear error message. The beta version's error messages are just confusing - if not incorrect.